# How should a tag and tag wiki for "En Garde!" be written since there are 5 games with the same name, and the question is not about the most popular?

Tags: discussion, tagging

We have a question [In the game "En Garde!" - How do optional routines work?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/6046/3389), which has had its tag [en-garde](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/en-garde) removed before because no tag wiki was created. I decided that I was willing to add a tag wiki so that doesnt happen again.

However, there are [five games with that name](http://boardgamegeek.com/geeksearch.php?action=search&objecttype=boardgame&q=en%20garde). Sometimes when I've come across games with the same name, the task has been easy because one version has been far and beyond more popular. For instance, I recently wrote the tag wiki for [trajan](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trajan). There are [two games with that name](http://boardgamegeek.com/geeksearch.php?action=search&objecttype=boardgame&q=trajan&B1=Go), but the question was about the one that is newer, and is currently ranked 49 on Board Game Geek where the next one is ranked 4087.

But in this case, the question is about [the version of En Garde!](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/7771/en-garde) that is neither the most popular, nor the newest. It's conceivable that someone may want to ask a question about one of the more popular or newer games with that name.

So how should the tag and tag wiki be written?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On Arqade, we have occasionally solved this problem by adding the publication year to the tag to uniquely identify the specific game. The new Doom game, for example, is tagged [doom-2016] to distinguish it from the original Doom game. The same approach should work here, at least in this case, where we already know that all of the games with that name were published in different years.

So, that question would be tagged with [en-garde-1975](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/en-garde-1975), and then the tag wiki can be written as normal, treating the tag name as a specific reference to one game.

Comment: I've gone ahead and changed the tag on that question. Thanks for the suggestion!